# Event only triggers when I click in the same tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the element I have some text that when the text is highlighted and the selection is retrieved, an event occurs like a menu.

When I click over some other text the menu goes away but if I click outside the element where there is no text, the menu persists.

I realize that text also changes the cursor and I'm wondering how to make it so that when a user clicks away from the highlighted text, the menu also goes away and not just when new text is highlighted or clicked.

```
$('element').on('mouseup', function (e) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  if (sel != '') {
    //event happens when text is selected
  } else {
    //event should go away
  }
});
```

**ANSWER**

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function (e) {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  if (sel != '') {
    //event happens when text is selected
  } else {
    //event should go away
  }
});
```

I just changed the event to occur on the outer most element of the page.

Comment: As sMilEy suggest you should add an event to trigger when element loose focus. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout should work

Comment: If you fix your issue please include your new code so people finding this question later can see the fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a new event that monitors if the mouse has left. You current code only monitors if the element has been selected so is half of what you want to do.